# Client-Site jQuery fileupload (multi-Upload)

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I'm trying to realize a multi-upload, but via the Symfony controller it won't work out completely.

My idea is to do a client-side upload via jQuery. So it looks like a multi-upload to the user, but the files are uploaded separately.

For each upload the field Description and Category should be added. So the user should be able to describe each file and add the appropriate category.

Multi-upload in the controller did not work so well with adding the fields "Comments" and "Category" for each individual upload. Hence the way via client side and jQuery upload.

**Symfony Controller:**

```
 /**
 * @Route("/upload/{firma}", options={"expose"=true})
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function uploadAction(Firma $firma, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $form = $this->createUploadFileForm($firma->getId());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $data = $form->getData();

        $file = new UploadedFile();
        $file->setFile($data['file']);
        $file->setPublic(false);
        $file->setBeschreibung($data['beschreibung']);

        $this->uploadHandler($file);
        $firma->addFile($file);

        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_firmen_listfiles', ['firma' => $firma->getId()]);
    }

    throw new UploadException("Es wurde keine Datei hochgeladen!");

}

/**
 * @param UploadedFile $uploadedFile
 */
private function uploadHandler(UploadedFile $uploadedFile)
{
    if($file = $uploadedFile->getFile()) {
        $dir = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . DokumenteController::DIRECTORY;

        $name = sha1(mt_rand() . microtime());

        $extension = $file->guessExtension();

        $uploadedFile
            ->setDateiname("$name.$extension")
            ->setPfad($dir)
        ;

        $file->move($dir, "$name.$extension");
        $uploadedFile->setGroesse(filesize("$dir$name.$extension"));
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($uploadedFile);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
    }
}

/**
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface
 */
private function createUploadFileForm($firmaId)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('app_firmen_upload', ['firma' => $firmaId]))
        ->add('beschreibung', null, ['label' => 'Beschreibung','attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Beschreibung ist optional'], 'required' => false])
        ->add('file', FileType::class)
        ->add('kategorien', ChoiceType::class, ['label' => 'Kategorien','attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Auswählen'], 'required' => false, 'choices' => UploadedFile::DATEIUPLOADKATEGORIEN_TRANSLATION])
        ->add('send', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Hochladen'])
        ->getForm()
        ;
}

/**
 * @Route("/files/{firma}")
 */
public function listFilesAction(Firma $firma)
{
    $files = $firma->getFiles();

    return $this->render('@App/Firmen/files.html.twig', ['firma' => $firma, 'firmen' => $firma, 'files' => $files, 'upload_form' => $this->createUploadFileForm($firma->getId())->createView()]);

}
```

**File Upload Twig:**

```
 {{ form_start(upload_form) }}

                            <div class="col-md" style="padding-bottom: 10px;padding-top: 10px;">
                                <center> {{ form_widget(upload_form.file, {attr: {class: 'btn upload_style'} }) }} </center>
                                <br />

                                <center>
                                    {{ form_label(upload_form.beschreibung) }}
                                    {{ form_widget(upload_form.beschreibung,  {attr: {class: 'form-control'} }) }}
                                    <br />
                                    {{ form_label(upload_form.kategorien) }}
                                    {{ form_widget(upload_form.kategorien, {attr: {class:'form-control selections'}}) }}
                                </center>

                                <br />
                                <center> {{ form_widget(upload_form.send,  {attr: {class: 'btn btn-warning upload_button_w'} }) }} </center>
                            </div>


                            {{ form_end(upload_form) }}
```

That's been my exact setup in the Controller. The attempt with the Multi-Upload.

**Controller The attempt with the Multi-Upload.:**

```
public function uploadAction(Firma $firma, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $form = $this->createUploadFileForm($firma->getId());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid()){
        $data = $form->getData();

        // array
        $files = $request->files->get('post')['file'];

        //loop
        foreach ($files as $file)
        {
            $file = new UploadedFile();
            $file->setFile($data['file']);
            $file->setPublic(false);
            $file->setBeschreibung($data['beschreibung']);
            $file->setKategorien($data['kategorien']);

            $this->uploadHandler($file);
            $firma->addFile($file);
            $em->flush();

        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_firmen_listfiles', ['firma' => $firma->getId()]);
    }

    throw new UploadException("Es wurde keine Datei hochgeladen!");

}
```

Comment: "but via the Symfony controller it won't work out completely." -> what is not working completely? Do you get an extension?

Comment: Always get NULL